# Creating a .conf file within Ubuntu to install wordpress

Tags: files, wordpress, configure

I am trying to install Wordpress on my Ubuntu WSL and therefore need to create a wordpress.conf file. Trying to do via Windows explorer completely fails as I do not have the rights to do it.
Now I am trying to create the file *with content* in Ubuntu, but don't know how. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does "create the file with content" mean in this context? in particular, where should the content come from?

Comment: You can do this with a text editor such as `vi` (vim) or `nano`. Many people tend to prefer the latter.